# What is this thing?

Tags: simplified-characters, character-identification

1 hour ago, my friend sent me a mysterious thing.
Can you tell me what is this mysterious thing?
Here's the mysterious thing:
[image]

Comment: according to Four-Corner Method 四角号码检字法 given character has 4-corner code 6042 with possible 5th digit 7（60427), look up in 4-corner code dictionaries  zhongguosou.com/zonghe/sijiaohaomashuru.aspx  for 6042 or  sijiao.911cha.com for 60427  or use Chinese handwriting recognition drawing character in https://www.mobilefish.com/services/chinese_handwriting_recognition/chinese_handwriting_recognition.php

Answer (score 3):

it's 男, you can copy and google it, it means male